# Google Map now showing Marker is I add custom icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

My code is given below. It is working now but if I uncomment icon line ( //icon: 'http://108.163.162.202:8080/finex/img/map_marker.png'), all the marker and their title do not display.

I want to add my custom marker in my page and my code does not allowing me.

Please help.

```js
$(function() {
  
  var locations = [
      ['Jersey City', 40.7178746, -74.0718356],
      ['Bronx', 40.8504989, -73.84934,5 ],
      ['Union City', 40.7667435, -74.0303289],
      ['Queens', 40.651018, -73.871192],
      ['Ridgefield', 40.8256436, -74.0153092]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7590615, -73.969231),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    navigationControl: true,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE 
  },
   

    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
  title: locations[i][0],
        //icon: 'http://108.163.162.202:8080/finex/img/map_marker.png',
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
  
   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<div style="height:300px;width:500px;" id="map"></div>
```

Comment: It [works for me if I use a publicly available icon](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/r67aeuks/)

Answer (score 2):

```
I did this in my project
<input type="hidden" value="http://108.163.162.202:8080" id="baseUrl" >
var baseUrl=$('#baseUrl').val(); 
 icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( 
                    baseUrl+'images/marker-new.png',
                    null,
                    null,
                    // new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    null,
                    new google.maps.Size(36, 36)
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The image has limited access with .htaccess. I have to enter username and password. Perhaps this is the problem? ;)
In addition you can leave the comma after the icon statement if nothing is following.